# A dependency loop

Tags: c++, inheritance, dependencies, containers, circular-dependency

I've designed an object inherits from `CDialog` (called `NBDialog`, and some derived objects of controls, such as `CEdit`, `CDateTimeCtrl`, `CComboBox` etc.
The `NBDialog` is one project, and the controls are in other projects.

Naturally, All of the controls are put on the dialog and use dialog's methods, so I have to 
`#include NBDialog.h`, and to add its `.lib` file for the linker.

I also want to handle all those controls from the dialog, so I wrote in `NBDialog.h` the following lines:

```
class NBCommonEditBox; 
class NBDateTimeCtrl;
class NBCommonComboBox;

CMapWordToOb* NBGetEditBoxMap();
NBCommonEditBox* NBGetEditBoxById(unsigned long ID);

CMapWordToOb* NBGetDateTimeMap();
NBDateTimeCtrl* NBGetDateTimeById(unsigned long ID);

CMapWordToOb* NBGetComboBoxMap();
NBCommonComboBox* NBGetComboBoxById(unsigned long ID);
```

This way `NBDialog.h` doesn't know the context of the object, but it knows they are exist and stores them in the maps.

Now I want to extend the `NBDialog` project and add a method which will get the print information of all controls, so all objects which inhertied from `NBDialog` will be able to use this method. The print information is defined in the controls implementation.

**EDIT:** If I write this method in `NBDialog.cpp`, I can't compile it, because `NBDialog` doesn't know the context of the controls' classes:

```
CStringList* NBDialog::NBGetMainTexts()
{
    CStringList* mainTexts = new CStringList();

    POSITION pos;
    WORD key;
    NBCommonEditBox* currEdit = NULL;
    for (pos = this->NBGetEditBoxMap()->GetStartPosition(); pos != NULL;)
    {
        this->NBGetEditBoxMap()->GetNextAssoc(pos, key, (CObject*&)currEdit);
        currEdit->NBStringsToPrint(mainTexts);
    }
    return mainTexts;
}
```

Is there a way to write the desired method?

Comment: You could maybe add an interface to these objects using multiple inheritance and cast to that interface you provide a virtual function for doing the queries that you need.  I'm not sure if this answers your question as it is a little bit difficult to understand what you actually want to do.  Could you show some pseudo code of your function to iterate your objects?  Do you actually need a single map of ID->CWnd to iterate?

Comment: @Pete I added a pseudo code. Now it's your turn...

Comment: Why would you be getting unresolved symbols? Are you sure the objects implementing those virtual methods in question are linked in?

Comment: @greatwolf They **can't** be linked in, as I explained in the question. If I link them, it will be dependency loop.

Comment: ok I see what you mean and Pete's suggestion makes some sense. But to be honest, I don't think `NBDialog` should be responsible for this. What if later on a new kind of control is added? You'll end up going back to `NBDialog.h` to add yet another `NBGet*Map` function.

Comment: @greatwolf You right. I also think about it. But do you have another suggestion? It's clear that `NBDialog` is the responsible of this, since all controls are located on it. isn't it?

Comment: @Pete As a java programmer, I'm afraid of using multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to define an interface for this and add that interface instead of the CObject.  The interface can offer a method to get hold of the control itself.  Don;t be afraid of multiple inheritance - yes it can have a slight performance penalty but it is not going to be an issue for you.  In this case it will be similar to interface inheritance in Java since you would use a pure interface.

You could also implement this in a similar way that avoids multiple inheritance but it adds more complexity that you don't need.

```
// Interface goes in the NBDialog project
class INBControl {
public:
    virtual ~INBControl() = 0;
    virtual CWnd* getWnd() = 0;
    virtual void getStringsToPrint(CStringList& strings) = 0;
};
inline INBControl::~INBControl() {}

class NBCommonComboBox : public CComboBox, public INBControl
{
public:
    // ... stuff ...
    virtual CWnd* getWnd() {
        return this;
    }
    virtual void getStringsToPrint(CStringList& strings) {
        strings.AddTail("foo"); // for example
    }
};


// NBDialog
    #include <map>
class NBDialog : public CDialog
{
public:
    // .. stuff ..
private:

        typedef std::map<int, INBControl*> ControlMap;
        ControlMap control_map_;
};

void NBDialog::addNBControl(INBControl* control, int id)
{
    CWnd* wnd = control->getWnd();
    // Do stuff with the control such as add it
    control_map_[id] = control;
}

// let the caller be responsible for [de]allocation of the string list
void NBDialog::NBGetMainTexts(CStringList& texts) 
{
    ControlMap::iterator i = control_map_.begin();
    ControlMap::iterator e = control_map_.end();

    for(; i != e; ++i) {
        i->second->getStringsToPrint(texts);
    }
}
```

Alternatively use a custom windows message and iterate all the controls, down-casting to CWnd and using SendMessage on its HWND.  Each control will need to handle your custom windoes mesaage.  You could pass a pointer to the string list in the LPARAM of the message.  This apprach is flexible but somewhat brittle/unsafe and could crash if you end up using the same message ID for something else by accident.

Comment: Thank you very much! When I have time I'll do the changes in the current inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation file (`NBDialog.cpp`) is free to `#include` the necessary headers to make this work (presumably things like `NBCommonComboBox.h`, etc.)  Because the `.cpp` file isn't `#include`'d by anything you won't cause any circular include problems.

Comment: I also thought so, but it failed. When I compile the `NBDialog` project, it messages unresolved external symbols of all methods of the inherited controls.

Comment: When you say "project" I'm sure this means you're using some kind of IDE that manages dependencies in a way I can't imagine.  So, you need to figure out how in your IDE to make sure that you have the proper dependencies available to the linker at link time, but this isn't a problem with your source code - you have to be able to link against the libraries that contain the symbols you're trying to use.

Comment: Right now I noticed that the unresloved external symbols are only of virtual functions. They have an implementation also in the base class, but the derived classes may have to use other implementation.